# Expected value where benefit and probability depends on stochastic variable

Tags: probability, integration

I am trying to calculate the expected benefit of an action, where both the benefit and probability of carrying out the action depends on a parameter c, which is distributed according to f, F'=f.

The benefit of the action is given by $\delta b_h-c$, and therefore the action will only be carried out if $c \le \delta b_h$.

The probability of that is $\int_{-\infty}^{\delta b_h} f dc = F(\delta b_h)$.

But since the benefit does also depend of the draw of c, i am not sure how to calculate the expected value.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best,
Esben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lat $a=\delta b_h$. The benefit is $$\mathbb E((a-c)^+)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^a(a-x)f_c(x)\mathrm dx=aF(a)-\int_{-\infty}^axf_c(x)\mathrm dx.
$$
**Edit:** If $c$ is standard normal,
$\mathbb E((a-c)^+)=a\Phi(a)+\varphi(a)$, where
$$
\varphi(a)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-a^2/2},\qquad\Phi(a)=\int_{-\infty}^a\varphi(x)\mathrm dx.
$$
**Edit-edit:** Since $x\varphi(x)=-\varphi'(x)$ and $\varphi(-\infty)=0$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{a}x\varphi(x)\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^{a}-\varphi'(x)\mathrm dx=\left[-\varphi(x)\right]_{-\infty}^{a}=-\varphi(a).
$$

Comment: Great. thanks! But is the result of the last integral? The one you subtract.

Comment: No simpler general expression (but perhaps you have a specific distribution of $c$ in mind?).

Comment: According to a normal distribution?

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: Will you take me through the steps? It'd be GREAT!

I guess this is how you get to the general solution? $\int_{-\infty}^{\delta b_h}\delta b_h f_c(x) -\int_{-\infty}^{\delta b_h}xf_c(x) =\delta b_hF(\delta b_h)-\int_{-\infty}^{\delta b_h}xf_c(x)\mathrm dx$.

But how do you get from $-\int_{-\infty}^{\delta b_h}xf_c(x)\mathrm dx$ to $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-(\delta b_h)^2/2}$ (I know its the formula for the dist)

Comment: See Edit-edit. If something is still unclear, just yell.

Comment: Thanks alot! 

I've run into the calculation of this benefit somewhere else, where they say that the benefit is equal to:

$\int_{-infty}^{a} (a-c)dF(c)$

Does that make sense to you?

Comment: This is the first formula in my answer.